# Minio: how to see which policy is applied for a user

Tags: minio

Using the minio client one can apply a policy to a user with:

```
mc admin policy set myminio getonly user=newuser
```

How can I at a later time find out which policies were applied in the past to user `newuser`?

Answer (score 0):

To view all the users and their policies:

```
mc admin user list myminio
```